# Can I access all values in NSDictionary from one value for key?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary

You might not get correct understanding from my question, because I even don't know how to express my scenario in on line. Coming back to my question. I have two web services one gives me products and other type of each product.

Response of first one:

```
Json : (
        {
        idProducts = 1;
        name = Product1;
    },
        {
        idProducts = 2;
        name = Product2;
    },
        {
        idProducts = 3;
        name = Product3;
    },
        {
        idProducts = 4;
        name = product4;
    }
)
```

Response of second:

```
json: (
        {
        Name = type1;
        "Products_idProducts" = 1;
        idProductTypes = 4;
    },
        {
        Name = type1;
        "Products_idProducts" = 2;
        idProductTypes = 5;
    },
        {
        Name = type2;
        "Products_idProducts" = 2;
        idProductTypes = 6;
    },
        {
        Name = type3;
        "Products_idProducts" = 2;
        idProductTypes = 7;
    }
)
```

The main problem is to get product type and make it set with product, if some how i could be able to pass value of "Product_idProducts" let suppose 2 it returns me the name. Is it possible ? if not then how can i combine these two value ?

Comment: you can get an array of all the values like,
 NSArray *arr = [yourJson valueForKey:@"Product_idProducts"]; 
if this is what you want...

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem or do you need more clarification?

Answer (score 0):

it's simple but you have to write a method to handle it, first create a for in loop on your second responce like

```
for (NSDictionary* dict in your.collection) {
    // get the value of product id using key "Products_idProducts"
    NSNumber* productId = dict[@"Products_idProducts"];
    // using sort descriptor fetch the product name from your first collection
    // also create a dictionary with all the required value and add into mutable array 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry if I am misunderstanding your question, but as far as I understand, you can simply use `NSPredicate`. Have a look at this example code I made for you:

```
NSArray *products = @[
    @{
        @"idProducts": @1,
        @"name": @"Product1"
    },
    @{
        @"idProducts": @2,
        @"name": @"Product2"
    },
    @{
        @"idProducts": @3,
        @"name": @"Product3"
    },
    @{
        @"idProducts": @4,
        @"name": @"Product4"
    }
];

NSArray *types = @[
    @{
        @"Name" : @"type1",
        @"Products_idProducts" : @1,
        @"idProductTypes" : @4
    },
    @{
        @"Name" : @"type2",
        @"Products_idProducts" : @2,
        @"idProductTypes" : @5
    },
    @{
        @"Name" : @"type2",
        @"Products_idProducts" : @2,
        @"idProductTypes" : @6
    },
    @{
        @"Name" : @"type3",
        @"Products_idProducts" : @2,
        @"idProductTypes" : @7
    },
];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"idProducts == 2"];
NSArray *filteredArray = [products filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSDictionary *product = filteredArray.firstObject;
NSLog(@"Result: %@", product[@"name"]);
```

`2015-03-25 12:03:05.381 Untitled[14762:956201] Result: Product2`

If this is what you wanted, you could simply wrap this functionality into a method that returns a product from a product type. Something like:

```
- (NSDictionary *)productFromProductType:(NSDictionary *)productType {
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"idProducts == %@", productType[@"Products_idProducts"]];
    NSArray *filteredArray = [self.myProductsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    NSDictionary *product = filteredArray.firstObject;
}
```

Preferably this should use enum for keys or your own model objects for more type safety - but this should get you started.